# How to convert the string into floating no by assigning the last two digits after the dot?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a function that returns the string value like this, for example -> 89923728.
This value can vary and it is actually a floating number, Where last two digits are always after dot. Example -> 899237.28.

Now I want to convert that string into floating number by assigning last two digits after the dot, - > 899237.28

How do I make that string into floating number and make the last two digits after the dot.

I have no issue in converting the value into floating number, but how to add last two digits after the dot.?

parseFloat(BatchID)

Comment: Divide by 100??

Comment: If you want a formatted representation that has exactly two decimal places, then that's very different from what you're asking. That wouldn't be a floating point number; it would just be a string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) function to convert the String into a Floating Point Number and then just divide by 100:

```js
console.log(parseFloat("89923728")/100)
```

As @charlietfl pointed out, you don't even need `parseFloat`, since JavaScript applies automatic type conversion when it encounters the `/` operator.

Comment: even `console.log("89923728"/100)` works dues to type cast when `/` operator used

Comment: Thanks Luca. Simple and Easy solution.

Comment: @James Please mark the question as answered, if it is. This helps both me and the community

Answer (score 0):

You could replace a dot before the last two characters and convert to number.

```js
var string = '89923728',
    number = +string.replace(/(?=..$)/, '.');

console.log(number);
console.log(typeof number);
```